# TED talks shortcode not working

Tags: shortcode, embed

I am trying to embed a Ted talk video using the shortcode:

```
[ted id=myid]
```

But it's not working. It shows the text instead of the video.
Is there any configuration I need to check to make it work?

Comment: What plugin do you use for that?

Comment: I followed the steps written here: http://en.support.wordpress.com/videos/ted-talks/ so i didn't install any plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is going to be a problem for you.

The `[ted]` shortcode is specific to WordPress.com - not to a self-hosted site where you installed the software yourself from WordPress.org.

The only embeds that WordPress.org's software supports by default are [listed in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds#Okay.2C_So_What_Sites_Can_I_Embed_From.3F):

- YouTube (only public videos and playlists - "unlisted" and "private" videos will not embed)
- Vimeo
- DailyMotion
- blip.tv
- Flickr (both videos and images)
- Viddler
- Hulu
- Qik
- Revision3
- Scribd
- Photobucket
- PollDaddy
- WordPress.tv (only VideoPress-type videos for the time being)
- SmugMug (WordPress 3.0+)
- FunnyOrDie.com (WordPress 3.0+)
- Twitter (WordPress 3.4+)

There is a plugin available for embedding Ted talks, though.  [TEDTalks Embedder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tedtalks-embedder/other_notes/).  But it only lists compatibility through WP 3.2.1, so it may not work with the current version (it may, but I can't guarantee it).

---

### Alternative Actual Embeds

Here's an alternative if you don't want to use a plugin.  Add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
// Whitelist the TEDTalks oEmbed URL
wp_oembed_add_provider( 'http://www.ted.com/talks/*', 'http://www.ted.com/talks/oembed.json' );

function ted_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // We need to use the WP_Embed class instance
    global $wp_embed;

    // The "id" parameter is required
    if ( empty($atts['id']) )
        return '';

    // Construct the TEDTalk URL
    $url = 'http://www.ted.com/talks/view/lang/eng/id/' . $atts['id'];

    // Run the URL through the  handler.
    // This handler handles calling the oEmbed class
    // and more importantly will also do the caching!
    return $wp_embed->shortcode( $atts, $url );
}
add_shortcode( 'ted', 'ted_shortcode' );
```

Now, you can embed TEDTalks two ways:

- By using the `[ted id=981]` way they do on WordPress.com
- By placing the url of a TEDTalk on a line by itself in a post (i.e. http://www.ted.com/talks/ze_frank_s_web_playroom.html)

Enjoy!

Comment: Oh,ok! And yes TEDTalks Embedder does not work on my testing site ( WP 3.4 ) but it could work on the site i need it because it uses a lower version of WP.

Comment: If it doesn't, I've edited my answer to provide you a way to add the shortcode handler yourself by dropping some code in your theme's `functions.php` file ... oh, and I tested it to work on the latest version of WP.

Answer (score 0):

The [Jetpack plugin](http://jetpack.me/support/shortcode-embeds/) will allow you to use the `[ted]` shortcode on your WordPress self-hosted site.