# ted talks embed fixed, but can't control size

Tags: embed

I used this changes to functions.php that are written in this post: [TED talks shortcode not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67740/ted-talks-shortcode-not-working)

But I can't figure out how to control the size/ratio now. The video is embedding as way taller than it is wide. Any fix for this??

Comment: Have you made any effort at fixing this yourself?

Comment: I looked at the php fix and wasn't sure how to add in size conditions. I don't know how to write that.

Comment: We have to dig into other Questions/links to find the actual code you are using? And probably **will not be** exactly as you are using it... Please, post the relevant code to the Question itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the size of the embedded TED video by using the shortcode:

```
[ted id="1650" width="300" height="200"]
```

If you want to have it predefined, you can use:

```
if(!isset($atts['width'])){
    $atts['width']=600; // Default width
}
if(!isset($atts['height'])){
    $atts['height']=400; // Default height
}
```

so the code [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67768/26350) will be:

```
// Whitelist the TEDTalks oEmbed URL
wp_oembed_add_provider( 'http://www.ted.com/talks/*', 'http://www.ted.com/talks/oembed.json' );

function ted_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // We need to use the WP_Embed class instance
    global $wp_embed;

    // width:
    if(!isset($atts['width'])){
     $atts['width']=600; // Default width
    }  

    // height:
    if(!isset($atts['height'])){
     $atts['height']=400; // Default height
    }

    // The "id" parameter is required
    if ( empty($atts['id']) )
        return '';

    // Construct the TEDTalk URL
    $url = 'http://www.ted.com/talks/view/lang/eng/id/' . $atts['id'];

    // Run the URL through the  handler.
    // This handler handles calling the oEmbed class
    // and more importantly will also do the caching!
    return $wp_embed->shortcode( $atts, $url );
}
add_shortcode( 'ted', 'ted_shortcode' );
```